# AEM6: social reviews - How to display the product average Rating of the users?

Tags: aem

I use the AEM 6.0 [social reviews](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/de/aem/6-0/author/social-communities/using-reviews.html) to give the users the possibility to review some product. This component works fine. Now I would like to display the average Rating of all users for the reviewed product, sothat the user can see the overall user review of this product? Is there any component which do that or I have to do that programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried the rating component? http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/social-communities/using-ratings.html

Answer (score 0):

The OOTB rating component dialog has a "Display Only"... when checked, it displays the average that you are looking for.